# Access route data from directives in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

```
const APP_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [

    {

        path: 'app/home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          name: 'Home'
        }

    }


]
```

If I have route configuration shown as above how do I access its `data` property from some directive.

```
@Directive({
  name: 'hello'
})

class HelloDirective {
 @Input('routerLink') link: string[];

 ngOnInit() {
    //HOW CAN I GET ROUTE AND ITS DATA FROM PATH/URL ???

    //const magicallyGrabbedRoute = pleaseGiveMeMyRouteFrom(this.link);
    //const myData = magicallyGrabbedRoute.data;

 }

}

<a hello [routerLink]="['app/home']"> Go Home </a>
```

In `hello` directive how can I get route configuration for the `routerLink` attribute's value ?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this @Lekhnath?

Comment: @Spikeh Sadly I couldnot figure out any solution for this.

Answer (score 10):

(**RC6**):You need to import:

`import { ActivatedRoute }    from '@angular/router';`

Then in your constructor:

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }`

The class should `implements OnInit` this way:

`ngOnInit() {
    const myData = this.route.snapshot.data['name'];
  }`

This is in case your URL is not dynamic. If dynamic you should use an observer and not snapshot.
p.s. for parents of parents just use: `this.route.snapshot.parent.data['name']`

Comment: This can be used to access activated routes data but I am not trying to  get activated route's data from some route Component instead I am trying to get route data from some link ,say : ['app/home'].

Comment: Well, if it's one of the parents you can use `this.route.snapshot.parent.data['name']` as suggested. If not, you can use any other component communication suggested here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html. Best might be via a service IMO.

Comment: Please look at my `ngOnInit` route method how I am trying to get `routerLink` attributes value and based on that value I want an alias of route configuration that maps the link/path.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe on route parameters by putting it inside your Component class. & have `private route: ActivatedRoute` in constructor

```
this.sub = this.route
  .params //.data //--> use data to retrieve route data
  .subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params['id']);
  });
```

You could also use `this.route.snapshot.data` to retrieve passed data in route defination.

Comment: This answer lacks to solve my problem. To what service should I provide some link so that it gives me a route/routeConfiguration/routeData in return. It could be any link not only the current/activated route.

Comment: Where can I find `RouteData` it isn't in `@angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2` ?

Comment: `params` should be changed to `data`

Comment: @Lekhnath yes, RouteData has been deprecated, please find update

Comment: I am not trying to  get activated route's data from some route Component instead I am trying to get route data from some link ,say : ['app/home']. Any clue on that?

Comment: @Lekhnath frankly speaking, I don't understand what you wanted to achieve? could you please update your question with more explanation?